Why do negative Sobolev spaces contain distributions?
The space $H^{-s}$ consists of all $f$ such that
$$\|f\|_{H^{-s}} = \int (1+|k|^2)^{-s/2}\hat{f}(k) dk < \infty.$$
What about this definition implies that $f$ may not be a function but a distribution? How can I see that this must be the dual space to $H^s$?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
